# What quantity is this "length" called?

Tags: list-manipulation

```
tmp = {x, y, z}^{1, 2, 3}
Times @@ tmp
Length[%]
```

This gives a length of 3. But I was expecting 1.

What is exactly this "length" of x*y^2*z^3 called?
I would think this as a scalar of length 1?

Thanks!

Comment: `Times @@ tmp // FullForm`. Take a closer look at documentation of `Length` too.

Comment: Perhaps you really want a test for the result being a List or not?  Then you might look at ListQ (undocumented tho).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation:

```
Length[expr]
```

gives the number of elements in expr.

in your case

```
tmp = {x, y, z}^{1, 2, 3} 
r=Times @@ tmp
(*x y^2 z^3*)
```

r is an expression with thee elements. to see this you do:

```
FullForm[r]
(*Times[x, Power[y, 2], Power[z, 3]]*)
```

the expression here is `Times` and the elements of `Times` are 3 (`x`, `Power[y, 2],` and `Power[z, 3]`)

Answer (score 4):

The `Length` operator will operate on lists, but if your object is not a list, it is not automatically considered to be length 1. When you apply `Times@@` to your `tmp`, it is no longer a list.

`Length` will apply to many other expressions. For example:

```
Length[p+q+r]
(*Output: 3*)

Length[a*b+c]
(*Output: 2*)

Length[5+2]
(*Output: 0*)
```

In the first case, the sum has three parts, so it is a sum of length three. Note that if you did `Length[List@@(p+q+r)]` you'd get 3 also.

The next one is only length 2 because the "outermost" operation has length 2. It is a sum of two things. You can even do something like `(a*b+c)[[1]]` or even `Length[(a*b+c)[[1]]]`.

The last one will produce 7 before attempting to evaluate `Length`, and because 7 is an "atomic" thing (it is not a list or other compound expression like a symbolic sum, product, etc.) it returns length 0.

Or try:

```
tmp2 = Times @@ tmp
Map[Length, List @@ tmp2]
```

Note that you **are** required to `List@@` the expression. I don't think `Map` will map itself over products or sums, so you have to convert `tmp2` back to a list, which would be `{x,y^2,z^3}`. Notice that `x` is not a compound expression so it has 0 length, just like 7.

Comment: `Map` *will* operate over non-lists.  For example, `Map[f, Times[a, b, c]]` gives `Times[f[a],f[b],f[c]]`.

Comment: Of course it will evanb, but **only if** you either convert it to a list (what I did) or to full form (which is basically what you did). `Map[Length, tmp2]` will still return 0 as expected.

Comment: @Artes, and KM, There must surely be a better use of your time and considerable talents. (I confess I now have this bizarre image of some sort of Mathematica smack-down tournament. This cannot be healthy.)

Comment: I said nothing of the sort. `f[1,2]` is, unless `f` is defined elsewhere, going to be seen the same as any full form expression like `Times[x,y]` or the original expression in the question. Just like I said. If `f` is defined, `f` will be evaluated first, and the length of the resulting expression will depend entirely on what `f` gives with those inputs.

Comment: The "not." Non-lists are **not** assumed to be length 1.

Comment: And no, `ClearAll[f];Length[f[1,2]]` returns 2. Meanwhile `ClearAll[f];f[p_,q_]=p+q;Length[f[1,2]]` returns 0, while `ClearAll[f,x];f[p_,q_]=p+q+x;Length[f[1,2]]` returns 2.

Comment: @KellenMyers oh, ok, I'm blind and stupid :P My apologies. p.s. I mean only `f`.

Comment: It was just a suggestion (he muttered, mostly to himself).

Comment: @Artes Isn't 3 months too long to be carrying a grudge against a random person on the internet for a few fictitious points? You already did down vote in retaliation [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57008/5) (not that I encourage it)... your post has been acknowledged as useful by several others and the OP. Why still hang on to one down vote? For the sake of your own sanity, some things are best ignored.